# Laravel ModelNotFound exception handling with namesapces

Tags: php, exception, laravel, namespaces

I have this problem where laravel ModelNotFound exeption handler catches all exceptions not only releated to eloquent.

I have added to `global.php` this code:

```
// this is default code
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);
});
// added code
App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $exception)
{
    //do something, in my case redirect to 404 or whaterver
});
```

Controller has this partial code:

```
namespace CompanyName\Admin;

class PromosController extends CompanyNameAdminController {

    public function show($id) {
        $promo = Promo::findOrFail($id);
    }
}
```

Now if I try to pass id that dont exist I will recieve white page, code in app error does not execute. Other problem is that this App:error catches all Exeptions, like not found conrollers etc, basicly every exeption.

What I am doing wrong? I got this idea from Laracasts Exeptions handling episode, but somehow Im missing something. Because I get no feedback form Laravel about problem I am stuck. I suspect that namespaces has something to do with it but I am not sure..

EDIT:
At last I found some feedback in console:
500 Internal Server Error
HTML:
Reload the page to get source for: http://cms.dev/admin/promos/533

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelNotFoundException` is not in that namespace, so it is not being found. Specify the qualified name:

```
App::error(function(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $exception)
{
    //do something, in my case redirect to 404 or whaterver
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the order of your Exception handlers. You have the handler for `Exception` first, as `ModelNotFoundException` extends `Exception` it gets handled by the `Exception` handler before it get's to the `ModelNotFoundException`. Simply switch them around and you should find it works as expected.

Comment: Seems like it works the same if I switch them. But I found some data in console -- 'edit' paragraph in my question.